# Winforms Toolstrip button image lose its color

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a simple toolstrip button. Once I setup the background image of the button, image lose its one of the color. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Before setup:

[image: Original Image]

After background setup:

[image: After setting up background image]

Somehow the arrow lose its color in the image. I am not sure if something to do with the transparency. There is no code. I just set the background image from properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolStripButton` class has an [ImageTransparentColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.imagetransparentcolor?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ToolStripItem_ImageTransparentColor) property. The arrow in your image seems to match this color (magenta by default).

Comment: I have tried changing the color already without any luck.

Comment: Then show us please your code, everything related to your toolstripbutton. You can find the designer generated code if your form.designer.cs file.

Comment: this.tsActivityStatement.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            this.tsActivityStatement.Image = global::COEAS.Properties.Resources.tActivityStatement;
            this.tsActivityStatement.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.tsActivityStatement.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;

Comment: After changing to LimeGreen its working fine. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a "ToolStripButton"
2. Right-click on the "ImageTransparentColor" property of "ToolStripButton" in properties panel and click on "Reset"
3. Set your image